# How to set Up XAMPP/Apache to make internet work behind the firewall

Tags: php, apache, proxy, xampp

I got a machine running XAMPP and two browsers, chrome and firefox. The structure of the network is:

```
LAN > Firewall > DMZ > Router > Internet > Registered Domain > database
```

I use Chrome for internet access, currently setup to pass the firewall. Meaning to say the config is like, the proxy would be the firewall and gateway will be my internet router. Firefox on the other hand has "no proxy" settings so it does not go out the net because it's blocked by firewall, but I'll be able to view pages on my Apache server via XAMPP running on my local machine and/or LAN.

Here is where it get's tricky: The PHP pages I got needs to run on Apache server via XAMPP but content is pulled at a registered domain database outside the internet.

**So the problem is**, if I run my php page from Firefox, I can see my page but the content  I'm trying to get from the internet is being blocked by the firewall. If I run the page from the Chrome, the proxy passes my connection outside the net where my XAMPP is not present so normally I get an error saying content not available. **I need to find a way to make XAMPP working and host my page while it gets it's data from the Registered Domain**

Any ideas how to solve this? **I do not want to change any setting on my firewall or router**, I was thinking about config of XAMPP or Apache that can do forwarding to outside proxy when content is not present. If my idea is valid, how do I do this?

**What I've done so far:**

1.) Right now I transferred my pc outside the firewall (connected via router)... it works fine so meaning if I put it back behind the firewall, I just need to configure something in XAMPP or Apache. That is what I'm looking for.

2.) I also tried swapping setting on Chrome and Firefox. Same problem, only reversed.

3.) I've also played around with the httpd-proxy.conf as suggested in the net but nothing is working for me. I do not understand Apache that much to be able to configure it properly.

4.) On another network where the structure is like:

```
PC >Router > Internet > Registered Domain > database
```

... my page displays fine with data displaying as it should.

5.) I tried using Chrome with proxy setup (with internet) after setting a virtual host but it did not work. It did not display the page and same error i get from chrome. Here is my setup.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin myname@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
    ServerName <IP address of my PC>
    ServerAlias <IP address of my PC>
    ##ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error.log"
    ##CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

the error is:

*Network Access Message: The page cannot be displayed
Explanation: There is a problem with the page you are trying 
  to reach and it cannot be displayed. 
Try the following:
Refresh page: Search for the page again by clicking the Refresh button. 
The timeout may    have occurred due to Internet congestion.
Check spelling: Check that you typed the Web page address correctly. 
The address may have been mistyped.
Access from a link: If there is a link to the page you are looking for, 
try accessing the page from that link.
If you are still not able to view the requested page, try contacting your 
administrator or Helpdesk. 
Technical Information (for support personnel)
Error Code: 502 Proxy Error. The ISA Server denied the specified Uniform Resource Locator (URL). (12202)
IP Address: (IP address of firewall)
Date: (12/9/2013 11:48:43 PM)
Server: (myFirewallServer)
Source: proxy*

6.) I tried configuring the Chrome's Proxy setting to make my IP address as an exception. It displayed the page but not the data. Same error as that with Firefox.

**PHP program are as follows:** I've replaced some contents for my protection.

```
  ...
  <?php    
      // Create connection
      $con=mysqli_connect(...);

      // Check connection
      if (mysqli_connect_errno())
        {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }

      $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT ... where ... " );

      while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {       
          $rowAA = $row1['Field1'];
          $rowBB = $row1['Field2'];
        }
  ?>

  ...

  <?php   echo $rowAA;   ?>

  ...

   <?php   echo $rowBB;   ?>

  ...
```

Comment: I don't see why you have to use such a complicated setup: just use a browser with internet connection for your internal pages too. Provide `/etc/hosts` entries for the 'domains' you fake locally, if required (or another means to resolve the domain name to a local ip address). Then, if your browser uses a proxy, define exceptions for that browser to _not_ use the proxy for certain domains.

Comment: Thanks. I tried the "define exceptions for that browser to not use the proxy for certain domains" did not work. I tried putting the ip address as exception, it displayed the page but same problem. Data display has errors.

I'll research on the /etc/hosts.

Comment: Hm? If that browser really does have internet connection (through a proxy or not), then it should be able to display external content, shouldn't it? What is the error when trying to open such an external page?

Comment: I'll add to the question the results so the configuration can be reviewed and verified.

Comment: Sorry, I only now realize that you are talking about a connection to a remote database that you cannot initiate due to the firewall blocking _that_ connection. There is no way (that I know of) to use apache or any http proxy to tunnel a mysql connection through a firewall. What does work is to setup an ssh tunnel through the firewall and connect to the mysql server through that tunnel. 1. setup a tunnel to the remote mysql server, 2. reconfigure your mysql setup inside php to the local end of the tunnel instead of the remote mysql server.

Comment: Thanks, I'll leave the question open In case somebody have a work around, right now I am forced to duplicate my database (outside the net) to XAMPP.

Comment: Hm? Why that? Why not use a tunnel? It is the standard procedure in such cases...

Comment: The actual php page I'm working will later be transferred on to the Registered Domain. I asked the question cause I just wanted to work behind the firewall. Editing the PHP or constructing tunnels for such temporary setup is not advisable, I think.

Comment: You don't really have to change the php implementation. You just switch the configuration which has to be separate anyway.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42817/discussion-between-henry-hughes-and-arkascha)

Comment: Sorry, maybe I got something wrong. I answered in chat and waited for 30 minutes. Have fun!

Comment: All good bro, Sorry to keep you waiting, somebody called me so I wasn't able to respond.

Page is run by XAMPP Apache but database I get it from the domain. I was thinking that it might be a port block issue for sql on firewall side. 

Yes, tunnel will work but I can not implement it due to office policies. Something I didn't want to mention up front on forum.